# How to plot (sqrt(1+x)-sqrt(1-x))/x?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am not able to get the correct graph of (sqrt(1+x)-sqrt(1-x))/x by using the following

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=stealth]
\tkzInit[xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,ymin=0,ymax=2,xstep=0.5,ystep=0.5]
\tkzAxeXY[color=black!80]
\draw[scale=1,domain=-1:1,smooth,thick,variable=\x,red,->] plot ({\x},{((sqrt(1+\x)) - (sqrt(1-\x)))/(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Please help me with this

Answer (score 9):

You only need to avoid the apparent singularity at 0, which can be achieved by setting the samples to an even number (for the symmetric domain at hand).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=stealth] 
\tkzInit[xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,ymin=0,ymax=2,xstep=0.5,ystep=0.5]
\tkzAxeXY[color=black!80]
\draw[scale=1,domain=-1:1,smooth,thick,variable=\x,red,->,samples=100] 
plot ({\x},{((sqrt(1+\x)) - (sqrt(1-\x)))/(\x)}); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The result can be improved (IMHO) by bending the arrow and using `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,ymin=0,ymax=2,axis lines=middle]
 \addplot [domain=-1:1,smooth,thick,red,-{Stealth[bend]},samples=100] 
  {((sqrt(1+\x)) - (sqrt(1-\x)))/(\x)}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.